# Full Screen Keep Resolution

Tags: xcom-2

When I start the game up it is always in 1280x720, and then I change it  to 1920x1080.  But on the next launch it never stays.  Is there a command line argument to set resolution?

Comment: any reason for the down vote?

Comment: No idea, looks fine, here's an upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar issue.
The following has worked for me:

In `XComEngine.ini`, ignore the `ResX` and `ResY` settings, and in the `[WinDrv.WindowsClient]` section set `MinAllowableResolutionX`, `MinAllowableResolutionY`, `MaxAllowableResolutionX` and `MaxAllowaboutResolutionY` to the resolution that you want.

Also, put a ticket in to 2K support - my doing so hasn't done any good, but the more people mention it the more chance it gets elevated up the bugfixing priority list :)

Comment: your correct the default it 1280x720